# How to select the smallest subdataframe from another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df1`:

```
    y     
0   3.0   
1   4.0   
2   5.0   
3   6.0
```

and `df2`:

```
    y     
0   1.0   
1   2.0   
2   5.0   
3   7.0
4   8.0
```

So I want to get to extract a dataframe `df3` from `df2` based on two constraints:

1. The first value for `y` in `df3` should be the smallest minimum number between `y` of `df1` (i.e 3) and `y` of `df2`:  so in `df2` there are two numbers less than 2: 1 and 2. So I need to choose 2 because (3-1) > (2-1).
2. Similarly for the last value of `y` in `df2` but in this case I need the smallest max in `df3`: so for 6 in `d2` there are two values bigger than it in `df2`: 7 and 8 so I need to select the 7.

So the expected output:

```
    y     
0   1.0   
1   2.0   
2   5.0   
3   7.0
```

Any help?

Comment: could you also add your expected output?

Comment: @sophocles check please

Comment: you use d1, d2 and d3 while your dataframes are df1 and df2. Do d1 and d2 correspond to df1 and df2? If so, please make that clear because it's confusing

Comment: why would the first number in df3 is ```1```, if in your first condition you say *so I need to choose ```2``` ? Or is that a typo and df3 should start from 2?

Comment: @sophocles  I mean for the first element (3) I want the bigger number in df2 which less than 3.

Comment: I still don't get what you're looking for